# Best way to integrate searching with pagination in cake php 3.0

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a web application build on cakephp 3.x and i want to implement searching on that data also, and pagination should work according to search result.
Can anybody give the best solution ?

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search is certainly your best bet

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you have a Articles controller and you want to paginate the articles with search as optional:

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController
{

    public $paginate = [
       'limit' => 25,
       'order' => [
          'Articles.title' => 'asc'
       ]
    ];

    public function initialize()
    {
       parent::initialize();
       $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    }

    public function index($search = null)
    {
       $query = $this->Articles->find();
       if($search){
         $query->where(['title LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%']);
       }
       $this->set('articles', $this->paginate($query));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best solution.
But I'm doing this way.

In my index.ctp, I put an search form

```
<?= $this->Form->create('search') ?>
<fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('Search');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

And in my controller

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $pes = '%'.$this->request->data('search').'%';
    $customers = $customers->where(['OR' => ['name LIKE' => $pes, 'lastname LIKE' => $pes]]);
}
```

Hope it works for you